# Sum all nodes from generated XML document names

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a single "directory" XML document like this:

```
<root>
    <N>A</N>
    <N>B</N>
    <!-- ... -->
    <N>Z</N>
</root>
```

And a number of separate XML documents with names like:

```
A_foo.xml
A_bar.xml
B_foo.xml
B_bar.xml
...
Z_foo.xml
Z_bar.xml
```

Where each contains a number, i.e., A_foo.xml would be something like:

```
<!-- A_foo.xml -->
<X>10</X>
```

I need to sum all of the values in X out of each of the subdocuments. I've tried the naive sort of XSLT/Xpath like:

```
<xsl:variable select="sum(document('./path/to/', //N, '_foo.xml')//X")/>
```

But with no success.

Comment: **1.** Why does `<N>A</N>` point to `A_foo.xml` and not to `A_bar.xml`? -- **2.** Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: It would, eventually, need to reference both. The point being I need to synthesize the name---not just use a name that's embedded in the XML. I can use any XSLT that's supported by Safari, Chrome, etc.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "eventually". If it's not related to your current question, then it would be best to remove it, as it is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in XSLT 1.0 (the only version supported by browsers) you would have to do this in two passes. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="values">
        <xsl:for-each select="N">
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="document(concat('./path/to/', ., '_foo.xml'))/X  "/>
            </value>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($values)/value)"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```